# Error during upgrade from Magento 2.4.1 to 2.4.2

Tags: magento2.4.2

I'm trying to upgrade to Magento 2.4.2, and looking for a fix to the following message that appeared. Please suggest what I should have done to prevent it.

```
equire magento/product-community-edition=2.4.2 --no-update
Warning from https://repo.packagist.org: You are using an outdated version of Co                                                                                                                     mposer. Composer 2 is now available and you should upgrade. See https://getcompo                                                                                                                     ser.org/2
Magento Open Source 2.4.2 is trying to change the existing order of the require                                                                                                                      section.
Local order:
   [
      magento/composer-root-update-plugin,
      magento/product-community-edition
   ]
Magento Open Source 2.4.2 order:
   [
      magento/product-community-edition,
      magento/composer-root-update-plugin
   ] but it will not be changed. Re-run using --use-default-magento-values or --                                                                                                                     interactive-magento-conflicts to override with the Magento order.
Magento Open Source 2.4.2 is trying to update require-dev:dealerdirect/phpcodesn                                                                                                                     iffer-composer-installer to ^0.7.0 from ^0.5.0 in Magento Open Source 2.4.1 but                                                                                                                      the field has been removed in this installation and will not be changed.  Re-run                                                                                                                      using --use-default-magento-values or --interactive-magento-conflicts to overri                                                                                                                     de with Magento values.
Updating composer.json for Magento Open Source 2.4.2 ...
./composer.json has been updated
```

Message below displayed on running the command `composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.4.2 --no-update --use-default-magento-values`

`Magento Open Source 2.4.2 is trying to change the existing order of the require                                                                                                                      section. Local order: [ magento/composer-root-update-plugin, magento/product-community-edition ] Magento Open Source 2.4.2 order: [ magento/product-community-edition, magento/composer-root-update-plugin ] Overriding local order due to --use-default-magento-values. Magento Open Source 2.4.2 is trying to update require-dev:dealerdirect/phpcodesn                                                                                                                     iffer-composer-installer to ^0.7.0 from ^0.5.0 in Magento Open Source 2.4.1 but                                                                                                                      the field has been removed in this installation Overriding local changes due to --use-default-magento-values. Updating composer.json for Magento Open Source 2.4.2 ... ./composer.json has been updated`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.4.2 --no-update --use-default-magento-values
```

Comment: Added the message in the post.

Comment: update "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": "^0.7.0",

Comment: Ran this command. It returns: Command 'update' not found, did you mean:

Comment: I meant edit composer.json and change the version for dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer to ^0.7.0

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue, fixed this way:
`composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.4.2 --no-update --use-default-magento-values` then `composer upgrade` and finally again `composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.4.2 --no-update --interactive-magento-conflicts`. There would be some prompt for you after this command, handle that and hopefully you're good to go.

Comment: It seems to have worked. When running the upgrade command, I found this error `Could not validate a connection to Elasticsearch. No alive nodes found in your c                                                                                                                     luster`

Comment: have you installed elasticsearch already? Its required for Magento 2.4.*. If installed, then make sure its running. `service elasticsearch restart`

Comment: Yes, elasticsearch 7 was already installed with the previous upgrade itself.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to magento/composer-root-update-plugin

https://github.com/magento/composer-root-update-plugin/blob/develop/src/Magento/ComposerRootUpdatePlugin/README.md